# How can i submit two forms in django

Tags: django

I have a template where i should have 2 forms and update them, I succeded to get the 2 foms in the same template, but when i make changes nothing happens !

**forms.py**

```
class OrderManageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['customer', 'product', 'quantity', 'status']

class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 5}))
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['full_name', 'address', 'phone', 'city', 'email'
```

**models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1500, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.full_name
class Order (models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    status = models.TextField(choices=ORDER_STATUS, default='Pending')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Order n°: ' + str(self.id)
```

**views.py**

```
def update_order(request, order_id):
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)
    cust = get_object_or_404(Customer, order__id=order_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        customer = CustomerForm(request.POST)
        form = OrderManageForm(request.POST)

        print(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid() and customer.is_valid():
            order = form.save(commit=False)
            customer = customer.save()
            order.customer = customer
            order.save()
        return redirect('orders')
    else:
        form = OrderManageForm(instance=order)
        customer = CustomerForm(instance=cust)

    return render(request, 'dashboard/order_details.html', {'form': form, 'customer': customer})
```

I put the 2 forms in only one form tag inside my HTML template

Comment: It probably creates a *new* `Order` and `Customer` in the database.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem
No, i've checked that ! nothing happens :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to feed the instances to the forms such that the forms can update the corresponding records:

```
def update_order(request, order_id):
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, id=order_id)
    cust = order.customer

    if request.method == 'POST':
        customer = CustomerForm(request.POST, instance=cust)
        form = OrderManageForm(request.POST, instance=order)

        if form.is_valid() and customer.is_valid():
            form.save()
            customer.save()
            return redirect('orders')
    # …
```

You should only redirect in case the two forms are valid, otherwise you can not see the errors that appear on the form. Furthermore you shoudld remove the `customer` from the `fields` of the `OrderManageForm`:

```
class OrderManageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['product', 'quantity', 'status']  ← no customer
```

Comment: Thank you,  that was helpfull !
i tried before to do it using CBV (UpdateView) and i didn't succed

Comment: @WalidOuzzane: The `CreateView`/`UpdateView`/`FormView` work all with a *single* form. While strictly speaking it is possible to subclass and alter that behavior, it will probably not produce an elegant solution.

Comment: @Williem Van Onsem
i have succeded to get the 2 forms in the same template, but i didnt find the way to submit , i've posted a question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70348979/django-updateview-cant-update-order-informations)